# Ruby on Rails: Use Curl command in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, localhost

I want to save the content of a page with the system command curl but it's not working.
I think it's a problem with localhost but I don't know how to solve this.

```
def save_page
    `/usr/bin/curl -O http://127.0.0.1:3000/category_plist`
end
```

Server output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:04:54 --:--:--     0
```

Comment: Your Curl command will work inside backticks, if the URL is correct. Because all that's happening is a sub-shell is being created and Curl is being executed in it, you should be able to do the exact same command in a terminal window and get the same results. I'd debug the problem from a terminal window first, then the sub-shell in Ruby should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your function to the following it should work ...

```
def save_page
  system("/usr/bin/curl -O http://127.0.0.1:3000/category_plist")
end
```

To test commands like this, exit your local webserver and run "rails console", from there you can enter a command such as this and get an immediate response ...

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0.rc4)
1.9.2-p290 :001 > puts system("ls -l")
total 56
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff   212  3 Feb  2011 Capfile
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff   924  6 Feb  2012 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff  3072  6 Feb  2012 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff  3943 16 Oct 23:16 MOR_git.tmproj
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff    18 12 Jul 19:06 README
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff   267 30 Aug  2011 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x   7 creativetechnologist  staff   238 30 Aug  2011 app
drwxr-xr-x  11 creativetechnologist  staff   374 13 Sep  2011 config
-rw-r--r--@  1 creativetechnologist  staff   157 30 Aug  2011 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x   6 creativetechnologist  staff   204  3 Feb  2011 db
drwxr-xr-x   3 creativetechnologist  staff   102  3 Feb  2011 doc
drwxr-xr-x   4 creativetechnologist  staff   136  3 Feb  2011 key
drwxr-xr-x   6 creativetechnologist  staff   204  7 Sep  2011 lib
drwxr-xr-x   6 creativetechnologist  staff   204 11 Mar  2012 log
drwxr-xr-x   3 creativetechnologist  staff   102 30 Aug  2011 logs
drwxr-xr-x  13 creativetechnologist  staff   442  6 Feb  2012 public
drwxr-xr-x   3 creativetechnologist  staff   102  3 Feb  2011 script
drwxr-xr-x   8 creativetechnologist  staff   272  3 Feb  2011 test
drwxr-xr-x   6 creativetechnologist  staff   204  3 Feb  2011 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   3 creativetechnologist  staff   102  3 Feb  2011 vendor
true
 => nil 
1.9.2-p290 :002 >
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Strange cause it's working with script/console but it's not with script/server. Maybe because it's the same instance?

Comment: I have started 2 instances at port 3000 and 3001, one for the client and one for the server. This way the code works. But will this work in production?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def save_page
    `/usr/bin/curl -s http://127.0.0.1:3000/category_plist` # -s will silent curl's output except the page
end
```

Comment: Already tried but it doesn't solve. The output in not written to the file. As I wrote in a comment above it's something related to call the server instance from the same instance.